# Is vars() a correct hash function for python classes?

Tags: python, caching, hash

I need to implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` function in order to allow `lru_cache` decorator in some instance function of the class. This class is supposed to be used as a base class for many downstream classes, so I've added these functions:

This seems to work syntactically for simple test cases, but I'm not sure if it's actually satisfies the conditions for a good hash.

```
def __eq__(self, __value: object) -> bool:
    return vars(self) == vars(__value)

def __hash__(self) -> int:
    # convert values to string for comparison
    return hash(tuple(sorted(str(vars(self).values()))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of an instance of a typical class can indeed be uniquely identified by the instance attribute-to-value mapping returned by `vars(instance)`, so you are on the right track, but instead of just the values of the mapping you should also include the keys, which can be generated with values by the `items` method of the mapping instead. There is also no need to convert the sequence to a string. And to guarantee that two instances with the same `vars` mapping generate the same hash, instead of sorting the sequence and then converting the resulting list to a tuple, which has a higher time complexity, you can put them in a frozenset in linear time:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(frozenset(vars(self).items()))
```

Comment: hi @blhsing can you take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77451525/why-doesnt-python-weakrefs-work-on-colab